# Following urls in javascript - Scrapy Splash

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I am extremely new to web scraping. I manage to extract information from static websites but am now trying my hand following urls and extracting data (which ofcourse involves some javascript). I have installed scrapy-splash for the same which is running perfectly fine.
The website I am trying to scrape is **https://www.ta.com/portfolio/investments/ari-network-services-inc** and the button to the top right side takes you to the next page (which is javascript, hence splash). I want to scrape some basic data (like company name, sectors etc) on all the pages till the last one. This is what I have done so far and I need help to correct this to successfully execute.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import urllib.parse as urlparse


class TAFolio(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Portfolio'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ta.com/portfolio/investments/ari-network-services-inc']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback = self.parse, args={"wait" : 3})

    def parse(self, response):

        companyname = response.css('h1.item_detail-main-info-heading::text').extract_first()
        sectors = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[0].extract()
        investmentyear = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[1].extract()
        status = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[2].extract()
        location = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[3].extract()
        region = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[4].extract()
        team = response.css('div.item_detail-main-info-group a::text').extract()

        yield {
        'companyname': companyname,
        'sectors': sectors,
        'investmentyear': investmentyear,
        'status': status,
        'location': location,
        'region': region,
        'team': team
        }

        next_page = response.css('li.item_detail-nav-item--next a::attr(href)').extract()


        if next_page is not None:
            yield SplashRequest(urlparse.urljoin('https://www.ta.com',next_page),callback=self.parse, args={"wait":3})
```

This gives me the correct information for the start_url but doesn't proceed to the next page.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I'm trying to understand where I'm going wrong in getting scrapy to go to the next page and crawl that as well, until there are no more pages to go to. Using this code, scraping stops at the very first page itself. @Rainb

Comment: I guess, you need to formulate your question better, it is not clear why would it not work without more context, or make a very specific example, it is very hard to help otherwise :(

Comment: Figured out the issue, Thanks anyway!

Comment: Post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update. The issue was in the order in which I had the scraping of websites. Below is the updated code which worked well.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import urllib.parse as urlparse


class TAFolio(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Portfolio'
    start_urls = [

    'https://www.ta.com/portfolio/business-services',
    'https://www.ta.com/portfolio/consumer',
    'https://www.ta.com/portfolio/financial-services',
    'https://www.ta.com/portfolio/healthcare',
    'https://www.ta.com/portfolio/technology'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback = self.parse, args={"wait" : 3})

    def parse(self, response):

        companylink = response.css('div.tiles.js-portfolio-tiles a::attr(href)').extract()
        for i in companylink:
            yield response.follow('https://www.ta.com' + str(i), callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):

        companyname = response.css('h1.item_detail-main-info-heading::text').extract_first()
        sectors = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[0].extract()
        investmentyear = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[1].extract()
        status = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[2].extract()
        location = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[3].extract()
        region = response.css('.item_detail-main-info-group-item::text')[4].extract()
        team = response.css('div.item_detail-main-info-group a::text').extract()
        about_company = response.css('h2.item_detail-main-content-heading::text').extract()
        about_company_detail = response.css('div.markdown p::text').extract()

        yield {
        'companyname': companyname,
        'sectors': sectors,
        'investmentyear': investmentyear,
        'status': status,
        'location': location,
        'region': region,
        'team': team,
        'about_company': about_company,
        'about_company_detail' : about_company_detail
        }
```